# Subscriber receives String with 'Data: ""'

Tags: python, ros, rospy

I have a publisher that sends a number from 0 to 6, or None. So I convert it to a string before sending it to make sure it can send the "None" value.

```
        self.pub = rospy.Publisher("jugada", String, queue_size=1)
        self.pub.publish(str(col))
```

and then i want the subscriber to receive it:

```
    class clicker(object):
        def __init__(self):
            self.jugada_sub = rospy.Subscriber("jugada",String, self.callback)

        def callback(self, data): 
            jugada = data
            print(jugada)
```

and instead of printing:

3

instead it prints

Data: "3"

which breaks up the rest of the code I need that number (or None) for.
I tried to str(data) and then try to edit the string to remove the 'Data:' part, but that doesn't work.
I tried to google it for like an hour, but can't figure out how to get rid of the "Data:" or how to change the message type to send only the string.

PS Later in the code i do:

```
        if jugada != "None":
            jugada = int(jugada)
```

and I get the error: int() argument must be a string

and if i do jugada = str(data) at the beginning, i get the error: Invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'data: "3"'

Comment: You're using some library, and it's not passing the raw message to the callback. Consult the documentation of this library to see what the type is, and how to get the raw data from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ROS messages are defined as classes, not built in types. For `std_msg` types you need to retrieve the data directly using the `.data` attribute. Take the following example:

```
def callback(self, data): 
    jugada = data.data
    print(jugada)
```

Another couple of notes. When publishing data it is usually a best practice to not pass the raw type directly to `.publish` and instead use a message type as follows:

```
output_msg = String()
output_msg.data = 'some string val'
pub.publish(output_msg)
```

Lastly, if you're publishing integer data you should use one of the integer types: `Int8`, `Int16`, `Int32`, etc